# Get name of enum and string value from an enum object of any enum type in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have been trying for a while to achieve this. 
I have seem some similar answers but it didn't work for me.
I am not an expert in C# so be aware.
(I don't even know if this is possible to be achieved)

All enums are in the same class.
All numbers are unique.

> My problem:

```
enum BAR
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
{

enum FOO
{
    C = 2,
    D = 3
}

public static string GetEnumName(object o)
{
    // Need help here
}

public static string GetName(object o)
{
    // Need help here
}
```

> Using Example:
>
> GetEnumName(BAR.A); // result = BAR
>
> GetName(BAR.A); // result = A
>
> GetEnumName(FOO.C); // result = FOO
>
> GetName(FOO.C); // result = C

Comment: If only all objects in C# inherited from something, and if only that something had a `.ToString()` method

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment

Comment: if .ToString() works I don't know how to get it working for many enum types. Sounds like a simple problem but I didn't get it working though...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So you are telling me you have used `.ToString()` and it does not work?  I find that _extremely_ hard to believe. If its not working you have to tell us why its not working, and any applicable error messages.

Comment: @maccettura he has not said that at all, what it would seem he wants is a generic way of getting the value of the enum without knowing what enum it maybe when he calls the method 

So he wants to GetName(object o) 

Without knowing that object o is Either Foo or Bar

Comment: @MartynWeber at some point OP _has_ to know what the value is (it has to be passed to the method after all).  `.ToString()` can be called inside the method on _any_ object to return its string representation.  There is nothing more generic than calling `.ToString()` since **every** C# object has it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these methods (use `Enum` as parameter-type instead of `Object`):

```
public static string GetEnumName(Enum input)
{
    return input.GetType().Name;
}

public static string GetName(Enum input)
{
    return Enum.GetName(input.GetType(), input);
}
```

Comment: If I may ask, why is `Enum.GetName()` preferred over `.ToString()`?

Comment: So all I had to do was exchange object to Enum. Awesome!!!

Comment: @maccettura: well, i didn't know the difference but look at the source code comment here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,1365cfeffd45409d,references

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta You still could have used object easily

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta, you did not have to change `object` to `Enum`, the code above would have worked just fine if the input arguments were still `object`, albeit with less type-safety.

Comment: Enum is just fine, that was all that I needed. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Just looking for someone to do the work for them I guess `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @TimSchmelter it [looks like](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0uPRIZ) `nameof` might be a good alternative too

Comment: @maccettura: doesn't help in the method, just where you call it

Comment: @TimSchmelter right, I meant in lieu of the method.  Instead of calling `GetName(SomeEnum.SomeValue)` just call `nameof(SomeEnum.SomeValue)`.  OP has the methods marked as `static` so its not like they need to be there to satisfy an interface or anything

Answer (score 2):

The `GetName` method is overkill as:

```
FOO.C.ToString();
```

Either that or you have a variable:

```
object o = FOO.C;
o.ToString();
```

Will get you "C" as a result.

For `GetEnumName` you can use:

```
FOO.C.GetType().Name;
```

or

```
object o = FOO.C;
o.GetType.Name;
```

Lastly, if your two methods are really intended to work only on enum values, the input value should not be `object` but rather `Enum` in order to enforce some level of type safety.

```
public static string GetName(Enum value)

public static string GetEnumName(Enum value)
```

Frankly, it's a little disappointing that you're spending time arguing in comments rather than just trying this stuff.

Comment: how do you know it is FOO.C? you only have object to work with

Comment: I don't think you understood my question mate

Comment: At some point (i.e. when you call `GetName`) you need to know the actual value. Why bother creating `GetName` at all when you can simply append `.ToString()` to the value and not call `GetName` at all. Unless, as one of the commenters said, this is a homework project.

Comment: I understood your question just fine. I don't think you understand how to abstract the concept.

Comment: what does it have to do with homework. I am at work. If I knew the type then I wouldnt need this at all. I want something to work with generic type. So you send any enum of that class and from that object I could extract the values.

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta you don't know the type/value?  How do you call these methods then?

Comment: It is in a different class. I posted an example on my question of how it should be used, but on the method I need it to be generic, in there you won't know the type. Tks for trying to help though

Answer (score 2):

```
    Below code should give you some idea....
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"GetEnumName(FOO.D):{GetEnumName(FOO.D)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"GetName(FOO.D):{GetName(FOO.D)}");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static string GetEnumName(object o)
    {
        // Need help here
        Type t = o.GetType();
        return t.Name;
    }

    public static string GetName(object o)
    {
        // Need help here
        return o.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer too. Thanks for posting mate :D

Comment: No problem, You should use Enum instead of Object if that's what you are always going to pass in the parameter

Answer (score 1):

The static `Enum` class has a method to get the name of the constant value given the type of Enum and the value. See the relevant [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx).  However, for reference it's as simple as

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(Foo), value);
```

I use this when I don't know the type of Enum being used (e.g. when I'm using a generic).

To get the name of the Enum, you have to use a little reflection on the type.

```
typeof(value).toString()
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I get it now, thanks for trying to help :D

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static string GetEnumName(object o)
    {
        if ( o is Enum)
            return o.GetType().Name;
        return null;
    }

    public static string GetName(object o)
    {
        if (o is Enum)
        {
            return Enum.GetName(o.GetType(), o);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: And what if `o` is not a `Foo`? do you intend to have a case for every possible enum?

Comment: @DStanley right, I thought we have only one enum, Update my answer

Comment: If you are going to bother putting in the check for `is Enum` why not just make the parameter an `Enum`...